# Ler arquivos em formato RTF e gerar um arquivo TXT

Tags: php

Tem como ler um arquivo tipo RTF e reescreve-lo em formato TXT, usando PHP?
Fiz uns testes usando `fopen()` e `file_get_contents()`, mas os resultados não foram os esperados.

Comment: Veja se ajuda http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria mais fácil se você utilizasse bibliotecas para esse fim.

https://github.com/jstewmc/rtf

Segundo o exemplo que está lá no Github, você pode fazer:

```
$doc = new \Jstewmc\Rtf\Document();
$doc->load('/path/to/file.rtf');
$doc->write('text');
```